# where do I enter my node commands and why?

Tags: javascript, node.js, shell, command-line, cmd

Node n00b here. I just installed node on my windows desktop and I'm wondering where I should enter my node commands and why... I have three options (see below). Oh, and if one of these (i.e. node.exe) is not intended for entering node commands, what is it for?

I have looked at the nodejs.org docs and I don't see a clear overview/explanation of what each of these are for and why it's recommended to use one over the other.

Thanks for any insight.

================================================

1) Windows Command Line:

[image]

2) Node.js command prompt:

[image]

3) Node exe

[image]

Comment: In the top one, type `node --help`, the other two are for evaluating JavaScript.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. It looks like the windows command prompt and node.js command prompt both respond the same way to node --help. Can those two be used interchangeably with no difference whatsoever?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**#1** This is simply window's `cmd`, you can type `node --help` there to get a general overview of what you can do with `node`

**#2** Also `cmd` but with some extra configuration, when you view the properties you'll see it's; `C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /k "C:\Program Files\nodejs\nodevars.bat"` Which basically means it runs `cmd` with a `.bat` script, that sets some environment variables, changes the title and prints some welcome message.

**#3** This is NodeJS' [REPL](http://nodejs.org/api/repl.html) which evaluates JavaScript within NodeJS' context. ( This is the same as running `node` from `cmd` )

Answer (score 1):

Usually you don't enter your code directly, but put it in a file instead. Create this file with the name `hello.js`:

```
console.log("Hello World!");
```

Switch to the directory of your file:

```
cd C:\Users\yourname\yourdirectory
```

Then run it with the `node` command:

```
node hello.js
```

And you should get the following output:

> Hello World!